# Using injectiontoken for module specific settings in angular

Tags: angular

I have an app with 2 main modules, web and admin.

Admin declares

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DISPLAY_LIFE_TOKEN,
      useValue: 6000,
    },
  ],
```

and web declares the same token with `useValue: 10000`.

Both modules contain a route and components that use a service with `providedIn: 'root',` that imports the token `DISPLAY_LIFE_TOKEN`.

Yet in the service, the config value is always `10000` even when calls come from the admin module.

See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r3ctm9?file=src/app/admin/admin.module.ts).

Did i misunderstand something about injectionTokens and providers, or is there another preferred way to set a module wide config?

Comment: @PankajParkar [I tried](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nqrjbe?file=src/app/admin/admin.module.ts), didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are singleton in Angular.

The only way around this is [lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules). This ensures a separate instance is created for services provided in the lazy module.

Remove `providedIn: 'root',` from the service.
Add the service to both module `providers` array.

```
  providers: [
    MessageService,
    {
      provide: DISPLAY_LIFE_TOKEN,
      useValue: 6000,
    },
  ],
```

And update the router module to use lazy loading:

```
   {
      path: 'admin',
      loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
    },
    {
      path: 'web',
      loadChildren: () => import('./web/web.module').then(m => m.WebModule),
    }]
```

(since this moves the path from admin module to app module, do not forget to also update the route in the admin module).

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3rop3p?file=src/app/admin/admin.module.ts)

Answer (score 1):

So unless the module is a lazy loaded module, the providers are not created as separate instances, that is the issue, I guess the latest value of `DISPLAY_LIFE_TOKEN` overrides the previous one.

One fix will be to use the providers array inside the root component of the module, this will ensure a separate instance is created for the provider `DISPLAY_LIFE_TOKEN`. Also `messageService` needs to have two separate instances! so remove the `providedIn: 'root'`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-main',
  template: `admin: {{value}}`,
  providers: [
    MessageService,
    {
      provide: DISPLAY_LIFE_TOKEN,
      useValue: 6000,
      useExisting: true,
    },
  ],
})

export class AdminMainComponent implements OnInit {
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q1nday)

The second fix will be to simply convert them to lazy loaded modules instead.

Comment: Yeah i too suspected the root cause is the singleton nature of angular services. Adding this config per component isn't really an option since i'm looking for a module wide config. I guess i should use lazy loaded modules.

Comment: @Dorus That seems like the best way!